# PHP MySQL Update Query Failing

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to execute the following query to update a record in a table.

```
require "conn.php";

$user_name = $_POST["username"];
$code = $_POST["code"];
$name = $_POST["groupname"];

echo "$user_name, $code, $name";

$sql_update = "UPDATE users SET group = '$name' WHERE username = '$user_name'";

if ($conn->query($sql_update) === TRUE) {
echo "success";
} 
else {
echo "fail";
}
```

The query fails and I'm not sure why. The connection is made and I'm able to echo the username code and name. Is there a reason why it's not working?

Comment: What class is `$conn` an instance of? And, do you know that this code is vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: usually, at least PDO's `->query` returns either `false` or a result set, but *never* `true`. So that might be the simple error here ... (I believe mysqli does the same). Also, in the failure case you could (for debugging purposes and on devel only) `echo $conn->error` (mysqli) or `print_r($conn->errorInfo())` (PDO). That said, **please use prepared statements!**

Comment: $conn is another file in my public_html folder which just defines the database name, username, password, and server name. This is my first time using php and i'm not familiar with securing against injections. I don't know if I should be concerned about them if its a very basic app and I'm probably not going to publish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not secure

Look at this code with prepared statements

```
require_once("conn.php");
$user_name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$code = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["code"]);
$name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["groupname"]);
$sql_update = $conn->prepare("update `users` set `group` = ? where `username` = ?");
$sql_update->bind_param("ss",$name,$user_name);
$sql_update->execute();
$sql_update->close();
$conn->close();
```

And conn.php file should be like this

```
$config = parse_ini_file('config.ini'); // Connection infos.
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['db_name']);
if($conn === false) {
 die("Something was wrong ! Please try again later."); // Error if connection not ok.
} 
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
```

Create file outside the public_html folder named config.ini to write connection data

```
[db_connection]
username = username
password = password
db_name = dbname
```

This function binds the parameters to the SQL query and tells the database what the parameters are. The "sss" argument lists the types of data that the parameters are. The s character tells mysql that the parameter is a string.

The argument may be one of four types:

```
i - integer
d - double
s - string
b - BLOB
```

Learn more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Comment: Did you even test this code? You have a major syntax error in the query. Plus, the simple fix to the OP's code was to escape their column name, being a reserved MySQL word; that's the real problem.

Comment: Yes I test this code and it works
What wrong in my code ??

Comment: Now you edited; so you saw/figured out what I meant then.

Comment: What is the point of `real_escape_string` if you are using parameterized bound values?

Comment: You're welcome. Edit: You deleted your "thank you" comment.

Comment: Yet, @RiggsFolly is right; you don't need that `real_escape_string` since you're using a prepared statement.

Comment: I use real escape string in any variables I use to make it more secure
That's what I think :)

Comment: Thank you, the real syntax error in my code was the reserved word "group". I put backticks around it and now it works.

Comment: @ArushShah you should change and not use `group` as a column name.